# Div data is not getting showed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Web Development, and i've written the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/debdebashis"   target="_blank">Debashis Deb</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="text-primary">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Interests</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid first">
     <p>Welcome to my Page, Here you can find most of the informations related to me</p>
</div>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that, my last div is not getting displayed in the page. What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: Displays fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/axtj8jwL/

Comment: I'm using bootstrap classes and am facing the problem. Try to put my code in this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_img_rounded&stacked=h , and you'll see the problem @David

Comment: @DebashisDeb: Don’t ask everyone to start copy&pasting your stuff themselves. Provide an example yourself. See [mcve]

Comment: @CBroe Fine, I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a fixed navbar you have to add a padding to the `<body>` of your site:

> **From the Bootstrap Documentation:**
>   The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>   Make sure to include this **after** the core Bootstrap CSS.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding

```
body { 
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

See the following snippet (little changes to support the responsive navbar too): https://jsfiddle.net/17mmmxps/1/